Ubuntu 24.04 Freezes at Login and After
The Problem
When the computer is powered on, Ubuntu boots up to the login screen. I then typically have a couple seconds where the keyboard and mouse work as expected, after which everything freezes up. The key/mouse become unresponsive and the clock at the top of the screen stops moving. No combination of keys I have tried work to bring up a terminal or otherwise get the system to respond. The only option is to force shutdown by holding down the power button.
System Specs/Install Process

Ubuntu 24.04 - running in real time
Created boot disk on a USB drive and then did standard install process from there (besides setting up real time operation)

What I Tried/Learned

Booting in safe mode is possible. I am able to boot and get into the terminal without problems. Freezing is not observed. I am able to turn on the network connection as well.
There appears to be some correlation between having an ethernet cable connected and not. When a cable is not connected (no wireless on this machine) this issue occurs nearly every login. When an ethernet cable is installed, the problem typically doesn't present itself at login, but has occasional occurred after login. On those instances I noticed that the network connection status shows up as disconnected at the time the freeze occurs.

